# Required Field Validation not working in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, requiredfieldvalidator

I have required field validation control for a radiobutton list. So if no values are selected then it gives me a  error which is fine. But when i redo select something and click the button then it does't not fires the server event of the button. Once i have the validation erro then whatever i do it disable the server side event. 
any ideas why is it happening my code

```
<div id="studysub_popul" runat="server" visible="false">
   <asp:Label ID="lbl_rdb_study_popul" runat="server"
              CssClass="questions"
              Text="2.Select your study subjects">
   </asp:Label>

   <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdb_study_popul" runat="server"
                        AutoPostBack="True" 
                        OnSelectedIndexChanged="rdb_study_popul_SelectedIndexChanged">
     <asp:ListItem>Individuals</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem>Population</asp:ListItem>
   </asp:RadioButtonList>

   <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" runat="server" 
                                ControlToValidate="rdb_study_popul"
                                Display="Dynamic" 
                                ErrorMessage="Study Subject is required" 
                                ValidationGroup="StudySubject">
   </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
        <td>
    <asp:Button ID="btn_s_section" runat="server"  
                OnClick="btn_studysubject_section_Click"
                Text="Next" ValidationGroup="StudySubject"
                Visible="false" />
       </td>
```

Comment: Check your console for any javascript errors.

Comment: Your radiobutton list has AutoPostback=true. Is this intended?

Comment: Which server-side event is disabled, the button or the radio button list auto post back?

Comment: Also, what logic makes the button visible, because in the markup posted (`Visible="false"`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add a validating group to the RadioButtonList definition too.

```
   <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdb_study_popul" runat="server"
                        AutoPostBack="True" 
                        OnSelectedIndexChanged="rdb_study_popul_SelectedIndexChanged"
                        ValidationGroup="StudySubject">
```

Comment: For some reason this doesnt work when the radiobuttonlist is in a Repeater control and the ValidationControl is part of the repeater